# Visual Studio Team system 2008 Database Edition GDR - ENU Compatibility with VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, compatibility, gdr

Is there a version of Visual Studio Team system 2008 Database Edition GDR - ENU available for Visual Studio 2010?

If not, is this software compatible with Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: Are you asking if the is a database edition of VS2010?

Comment: Yes, and if not does the 2008 version work with VS2010. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whilst there are no longer specific editions for Database development, the premium edition of Visual Studio 2010 includes [database design tools](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison)